# Unable to launch springboot app deployed in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to deploy Springboot Rest Service into openshift @https://manage.openshift.com/. It shows Build successful also shows 1 pod running. But when I launch route url, it says "Application is not available" and detailed message as below, please assist:

> **Application is not available** 
>   The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is
>   still starting.
>
> Possible reasons you are seeing this page:
>
> The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.
>
> The host exists, but
>   doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed
>   correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
>
> Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources
>   exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have
>   at least one pod running.

I've verified in OC console that service showing already running:

```
oc get po -o wide
NAME                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
myspringcloudapp-1-build    0/1     Completed   0          69m   10.131.2.216   ip-10-0-138-3.ec2.internal     <none>           <none>
myspringcloudapp-1-deploy   0/1     Completed   0          67m   10.129.8.23    ip-10-0-130-212.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
myspringcloudapp-2-deploy   0/1     Completed   0          32m   10.131.8.86    ip-10-0-141-141.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
myspringcloudapp-2-tb99l    1/1     Running     0          32m   10.130.6.101   ip-10-0-153-2.ec2.internal     <none>           <none>

oc get svc
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
myspringcloudapp   ClusterIP   172.30.229.134   <none>        8080/TCP   69m
```

Below is my SpringBoot Rest service, which is running when launched in local. 
But same code I've moved to github public repo (https://github.com/polireddyv/SpringExampleRepo) and trying to deploy in openshift. But unable to launch service url.

```
package com.example.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
//@CrossOrigin(origins= {"http://localhost:4200"})
public class HelloWorldController {

    @GetMapping(path="/hello-world-bean")
    public HelloWorldBean getHelloWorldBean() {
        return new HelloWorldBean(10, "Hello ... from REST service");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `oc rsh` to get into the container and then used `curl localhost:8080` and `curl $HOSTNAME:8080` to verify whether your application is responding locally and via the pod hostname, on the port the service is setup to say it is listening on?